# printing protovis output (programmatically)

Tags: javascript, protovis

I'm pondering switching to protovis for visualizations. One thing that keeps me skeptical however - since protovis creates its output as a div in a browser, I wonder if there is any at least semi-automatic way for me to create a bunch of images at once without opening each one and pressing "print" manually.

So the question would be:

- do you think I can use a browserless JS engine like V8 to execute the code and print the result?
- can I automate opening and printing within a browser?
- is there another way to get automated images from protovis?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this Google Groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/protovis/browse_thread/thread/ee5737796b4235eb) about this very topic.

Comment: well thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for (figured it wouldn't be entirely trivial...)

Comment: @Nicolas: did you see [the last post](http://groups.google.com/group/protovis/msg/8a70b0e274255b36), which includes a self-contained demo? Looks like you can pretty much take that and go from there.

Comment: yea, tried it out and it works, all that's needed is a little script around it to make conversion fully automatic, shouldn't be much of a problem. I'll post here if I do this. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.phantomjs.org/

It is a headless browser.

It can do exactly what you want :
http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Rendering

rasterize.js:

```
if (phantom.state.length === 0) {
    if (phantom.args.length !== 2) {
        console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        var address = phantom.args[0];
        phantom.state = 'rasterize';
        phantom.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
        phantom.open(address);
    }
} else {
    var output = phantom.args[1];
    phantom.sleep(200);
    phantom.render(output);
    phantom.exit();
}
```

An example to produce the rendering of the famous Tiger (from SVG):

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://ariya.github.com/svg/tiger.svg tiger.png
```

[image]